# How to enable an unsupported and expired excel plugin?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel add-in which is saved in xlam format. It was a free download and the company that made it is no longer updating it. I tried contacting them with no reply.

If I add the add-in to a workbook and open the Visual Basic for Applications editor to view the code, the project gives a "Project Locked - Project is Unviewable" error. When I try to use the add-in, the first dialog box for setting up the configuration is presented, but selecting an option says, "This license has already been expired. Please download new version."

Any advice on workarounds to allow the add-in to continue to work? Can I convert it to a zip file, edit something, and convert it back to an xlam?

Comment: Even if you convert it, it appears it requires a license to use it, which you don’t have.  That’s a hurdle you won’t be able to get around

Comment: Let’s ignore the ethics/legality of a license and look at the technical hurdle. If it was free, but now no longer supported, I am willing to make the assumption that there will be no repercussions for modifying it. What if this were an add-in that an in-house rogue developer created?

Comment: Also, the download does not contain a license file, nor does the website state a single license term.

Comment: But neither of those examples are actually what’s going on though

Comment: The developer is in the easiest position to maintain it.  It they are no longer supporting it, it suggests that there are technical hurdles that they consider to be no longer worth the effort.  That suggests that there is no simple workaround.

Comment: Presumably you know what this add-in does. Have you considered reverse engineering it?

Comment: Such tools have full proof security and not possible to crack easily. If you are getting message, Add-Ins licence has been expired download new version. In this case wise step should be download it. One more possibility is, download and use, "Wordpress Far Future Expiry Plugin" to activate it.

Comment: The thing is, there IS no new version. They used to create a new version every year, and force people to download it. The last one was released in 2015. I’m working on doing it myself through the help of statistics textbooks and the NIST website.

Comment: @fixert123...or they have moved on to other projects. Life often gets in the way and people move on. Especially for free software.